# How to create a range of dates via start and end date using partition?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake and I am trying to generate a date sequence in the form of new rows which are derived from an individual account's date range. For example:

Input

```
id | start_date | end_date  | region | amount
1  | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03| US     | 20
```

Output

```
id | start_date | end_date  | region | amount
1  | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03| US     | 20 
1  | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-03| US     | 20 
1  | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-03| US     | 20
```

I have 1000's of ids in my dataset, so I need to add a partition by id somehow into this. Is this possible using Snowflake/Sql?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use generator table and join the table with your table and calculate the record.

Temp table created

```
create or replace table t1(id int, startdate date, enddate date,region string, amount int);
```

Inserted the value

```
insert into t1 values
(1,'2020-09-01','2020-09-08','US',20 ),
(2,'2020-02-01','2020-02-03','US',20 );
```

The Query you asked for

```
select t1.id,t1.startdate + n startdate, startdate + datediff('days',t1.startdate,t1.enddate) enddate,region,amount
from t1 join
     (select seq4() as n
      from table(generator(rowcount => 400)) g
     ) n
     on n.n <= datediff('days',t1.startdate,t1.enddate)
     order by id;
```

Output

```
ID  STARTDATE   ENDDATE     REGION  AMOUNT
1   2020-09-01  2020-09-08  US  20
1   2020-09-02  2020-09-08  US  20
1   2020-09-03  2020-09-08  US  20
1   2020-09-04  2020-09-08  US  20
1   2020-09-05  2020-09-08  US  20
1   2020-09-06  2020-09-08  US  20
1   2020-09-07  2020-09-08  US  20
1   2020-09-08  2020-09-08  US  20
2   2020-02-01  2020-02-03  US  20
2   2020-02-02  2020-02-03  US  20
2   2020-02-03  2020-02-03  US  20
```

This one can even handle if u have different ID.

Comment: this is not working when my ids all have different start and end dates. Can you advise.

Comment: @t The only reason

Comment: @titu84hh I have edited the script to have any number of ids, and it should work. In case the startdate and enddate difference is more than 400 days , then simply increase the rowcount of generator table

Answer (score 0):

One method uses recursive CTEs:

```
with recursive cte(d, start_date, end_date, region, amount) as (
       select id, start_date, end_date, region, amount
       from t
       union all
       select id, start_date + interval '1 day', end_date, region, amount
       from cte
       where start_date < end_date
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Comment: Would this solution account that the start and end dates for each ID is different (which created respective date ranges,i.e. rows per id)?

Comment: @titu84hh . . . This creates the range for each `id`.

Comment: Loff In snowflake I am NOT able to use recursive somehow. I am using your command as my third sub-query or CTE. Is the premise for this to work that your CTE needs to be the first in sequence? I am not sure why its not working for all ids with their respective start and end date

Comment: @titu84hh . . . In Snowflake, the recursive CTEs require a column list.